# EF 6 Code First storing an entity Reference to specific child in a one of the collections on the entity

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I have a domain model that has a collection of entities configured in the normal 1 to many relationship, however I want to store a reference to a specific item in that collection using a FK in this model

> The list as defined in the model

```
public ICollection<SLWOUpdate> Updates { get; set; }
```

> The reference to the specific item in the list

```
public int? SLWOUpdateId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("SLWOUpdateId")]
public virtual SLWOUpdate LastUpdate { get; set; }
```

Of course the code is responsible for updating the specific item as opposed to having EF do it.

Is this kind of relationship configurable in EF?

The reason I want to do this is for querying filtering purposes as part of complex query that must execute as one statement

Comment: You can build your model like this, Entity Framework will *not* automatically make `LastUpdate` the last update (any time you add a `SLWOUpdate` to the `Updates` property of the parent, you will have to *manually* update `LastUpdate` (or build some sort of convenience method to do it).

Comment: I do manually update it when adding an     SLWOUpdate entity into the collection  and it works until pulling the entity AND its Updates collection.. EF Complains about needing a Fk on the SLWOUpdate entity named SLWOUpdate_Id.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding a new domain model to represent the LastUpdate which simply holds a primary key to this entity and a FK to the LastUpdate

> New Domain Model to represent the Last Update

```
public virtual SLCurrentWOUpdate LastUpdate { get; set; }

public class SLCurrentWOUpdate
{

    [Key]
    public int SLWorkOrder_Id { get; set; }

    public SLWorkOrder SLWorkOrder { get; set; }

    public int? SLWOUpdateId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SLWOUpdateId")]
    public SLWOUpdate SLWOUpdate { get; set; }

}
```

I can query this as part of a larger more complex set of predicates... I just have to reach into the model one reference deeper:

```
db.SLWorkOrders
.Where(t => t.TAutoDeclined != null && t.TClosedPendingPayment != null)
.Where(t => t.LastUpdate.SLWOUpdate.UpdateStatusType.SystemName == "CHANGE_PRIORITY");
```

Feels kind of hackish.. but it works..